# Render and Bootstrap Laravel 4

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I use render to convert the blade into string and attach as pdf content.

```
$html = View::make('tpl',compact('aa','bb'))->render();
```

Whenever I add bootstrap link or any other link in blade,

```
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

laravel will return to me this error:

> Call to a member function append_child() on a non-object

Why and how to solve this? I'm using Laravel 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Try with below:

`$html = View::make('tpl',compact('aa','bb'))->__toString();`

It will give you the view in string